# What factors determine efficiency of a lookup table?

Tags: c, lookup, trigonometry

I've been working on a synthesizer project for the past few weeks, implementing a set of C based numerically controlled oscillators that feed their output to a DAC on an FPGA.

One thing that I tried was to use a lookup table to more efficiently determine the sine values of a given tone. For example, consider the following code:

```
PhaseArray[NOTE1-1][idx]  = ((PhaseArray[NOTE1-1][!idx]  + SigmaArray[NOTE1-1])  % (MODULO_CONST) );
....
PhaseDivArray[NOTE1-1][idx]  = PhaseArray[NOTE1-1][idx]  >> 10;
....
audio = ((iNoteOn[NOTE1-1])  * (SINE_TABLE[PhaseDivArray[NOTE1-1][idx]])) +
....
```

Now this is the thing that confuses me. I have a fair number of phase accumulators running at the same time without issue. I can get more than a dozen notes to play correctly when I don't bother with the sine lookup and just use an effective square wave signal.

But the second I start using the SINE_TABLE[1024] lookup I have defined (which is a `static` table full of unsigned 16 bit integer values for the sine curve) the slowdown is immediate to the point where the same micro-controller struggles to produce 3 tones at the right speed for buffered playback.

What is it that causes the lookup table to be so inefficient? Is it something to do with the way the table might be defined in memory?

Comment: You are making assertions that we can't verify based on incomplete info given. Why do you think it is lookup table inefficient itself and not just the fact that you are doing more work? You are comparing the absence of an operation with the presence of the operation - so of course the more code case will perform worse.

Comment: Array lookups like you describe are very fast, O(1) constant time is as fast as it gets. There is probably more to your problem than just the time taken for the lookup. I would suggest using a profiler to determine where the bottleneck is, but I'm not very familiar with C tools.

Comment: @matt, the asymptotic complexity of an operation speaks to how it *scales* with input size, not to how fast or slow it is.  A constant-time operation can still be very slow.

Comment: @Ketta, you've really not given us much to go on.  A [mcve] demonstrating the difference between your higher- and lower-performance implementations would give us something we could actually talk about.

Comment: Speculation: if use of `SINE_TABLE` involves introduction of floating-point arithmetic where none was used before then the FP operations might be responsible for more of the performance difference than the array lookups.  That would be especially likely if your FP is implemented in software, instead of via a hardware FPU.

Comment: @John Bollinger yes, good point, my comment is probably not very helpful.

Comment: @kaylum, you are right. I just was kind of shocked by how much this indexing operation reduces the performance of the system.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I may not have a chance to put together a proper example right now, but for what its worth the phase array being used as a moving index is the only thing that differs between my two methods of sound synthesis.

Comment: @Ketta, if you cannot present a complete example then we can only make guesses, not reliable answers.  As guesses go, however, I'm still liking floating-point arithmetic is the main component of the extra work your modified program performs.  Performing table lookups certainly does involve more work than not doing so, but it's rarely costly in any absolute sense.